# Issue while configuring nginx in ec2 ubuntu server with Bitnami Configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to cofigure nginx for reverse proxy in my ec2 server. My application starts with port 9000. So i added settings to nginx.conf file as below :

```
server {
       listen 80;
       location / {
           proxy_pass http://localhost:9000;
       }
}
```

After this i did 'service nginx start' and no response message, not even an error. I tried 'service nginx restart' and it is showing 'fail' message.
In my ec2 instance, i've port 80 listening to all requests.

## *Edit*

I have bitnami configured on my instance, so it has apache as web server running. I don't want to disturb the current configuration. How could i do this with apache2 ?

Answer (score 1):

For nginx, please try this bare-minimum configuration:

```
server {

  listen 80;

  location / {

  proxy_set_header        Host $host;
  proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

  # Fix the "It appears that your reverse proxy set up is broken" error.
  proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:9000;
  proxy_read_timeout  90;

  }
}
```

Comment: Still the same error. On `service start nginx` nothing shows up and on restart it shows 'fail'.

Comment: can you paste error logfile entries? So we might see what's wrong and where the error comes from. What do you mean by "this code under http?"?

Comment: In nginx.conf file we have http section

Comment: ah okay, so nginx.conf is the wrong place to edit this. nginx.conf sets global configuration parameters, but usually not the configuration on how to handle website-requests / website parameters.
please refer to [How to Configure Nginx](https://www.linode.com/docs/websites/nginx/how-to-configure-nginx) to the section "Server (Virtual Domains Configuration)" to get more details on this task. You need to edit this file: "/etc/nginx/sites-available/default".

Comment: root@ip-172-31-21-246:/var/log/nginx# vi error.log
2015/10/20 16:11:53 [emerg] 2554#0: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2015/10/20 16:11:53 [emerg] 2554#0: bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)

Comment: ah thanks for this. It shows that another application (maybe apache?) is running on port 80. Nginx can't start because it cannot bind to an already used port 80. please user "sudo netstat -tulpn |grep :80" to see what application uses port 80.

Comment: tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      1470/httpd.bin

Comment: is this a production server or just a local server for testing purpose? seems like there is running a server using IP v6 on Port 80. if we are in testing environment: please do "ps aux |grep httpd.bin". This will show up something similar to "www-data 20257  0.0  0.0  96868  2948 ?        S    Sep16   7:24 httpd.bin". So then you do a "sudo kill -9 20257", this command will kill the proccess the hard way. Please fill in the number you see for the process instead of 20257. Then start nginx again.

Comment: root      1470  0.0  2.3 206564 23868 ?        Ss   03:30   0:00 /opt/bitnami/apache2/bin/httpd.bin -f /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
daemon    1471  0.0  1.4 1312772 15072 ?       Sl   03:30   0:02 /opt/bitnami/apache2/bin/httpd.bin -f /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
daemon    1472  0.0  1.6 1306072 17208 ?       Sl   03:30   0:02 /opt/bitnami/apache2/bin/httpd.bin -f /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
root      3811  0.0  0.0  11740   944 pts/0    S+   06:57   0:00 grep --color=auto httpd.bin

Comment: This is a production server, i haven't created separate instance for testing.

Comment: I think i''ve to kill all the four values from the above ?

Comment: I've configured bitnami and apache is pre-configured in it.

Comment: uhhh wait. When this is a productive server, with my command suggested you kill all the webserver processes. So no one will be able to browse to this server and see content.. If this is okay - and please note, I'm not responsible if starting the server fails... then we can proceed. Usually I would do this in a testing environment. 
Currently you run bitnami with apache. Is the stuff from bitnami used in your environment?

Comment: Yes, bitnami is used. My project runs on mean stack, so bitnami is used here. So should i configure the reverse proxy on apache2 ?

Comment: <VirtualHost *:443>


     
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:9000/

    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:9000/



</VirtualHost>

Comment: this would make more sense - as apache2 already runs a production configuration. Please modify your question so other users can see what the actual problem is. Add infos like running bitnami apache2, the infos what processes are running and on which port. Please refer to [Apache Tutor](http://www.apachetutor.org/admin/reverseproxies) to see how you can do this with Apache2. HTH

Comment: nope it won't because configs in nginx and apache differ. please refer to my link to see how it works with apache2.

Comment: Hi, i got it working with apache. My answer is below. Thanks for the hints. Good day

Answer (score 0):

As my instance is pre-configured by bitnami, i used apache for reverse proxy. I added the following to the httpd.conf file and it worked like a charm.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 Servername domainname.com
 ProxyPass / http://localhost:9000/
 ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:9000/
</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks semm0 for the hints.